# Safari Cuts off fixed image at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have set up an image to be shown at the bottom of every page on a wordpress site using the css below. It displays correctly within chrome and firefox however in safari it seems to site lower? perhaps because of the elastic scroll affect?

http://forever.electricmustard-dev.co.uk/home/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you remove the `background-attachment: fixed;` CSS property from the footer (**#mk-footer**) or change it to `background-attachment: initial;` in your stylesheet it'll work.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these work, it seems to be the bottom: 0; code that safari doesn't like?

Comment: It looks like there is some inline CSS that's getting loaded after your theme's stylesheet ( `<style id="theme-dynamic-styles-inline-css" type="text/css">...</style>`) So, you might have to use !important to make the desired change stick, like so: `background-attachment: initial !important;` Otherwise, you'd have to enqueue your theme's stylesheet to load after the inline styles get loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I have been using !important;

Comment: Is it still not working even with you using !important?

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I have been using !important;
Changing it to initial does indeed put it at the bottom but my aim is to have it fixed at the bottom of the window not the page? as I said the current code works perfectly in chrome and firefox its just safari seems to curt of the bottom! http://i61.tinypic.com/346x69s.jpg

Comment: Maybe I'm just misunderstanding you, but when I change the CSS to initial the footer image stays fixed at the bottom of the Safari browser window no matter how tall/short the window or even if zoomed in/out. Maybe we can [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87711/safari-cuts-off-fixed-image-at-the-bottom) about live in this chat room so we don't keep going back and forth here.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation for chat, try this? https://us21.chatzy.com/61381310325697

Comment: Just noticed that I missed some extra code that conflicted this... your solution was perfect! thank you!