# Safari chops off image including ( png, svg )

Tags: html, css, safari

The images are showing properly on other browsers e.g chrome, firefox except safari. The safari seems to chop off images

The following is the correct behavior when using chrome and firefox

[image]

In safari its chop off images

[image]

My HTML 5 Code is

```
<div class="sound-control" style="position: absolute;left:0;top:0">
        <button  class="sound-control-item" id="mute-btn">
            <img src="/assets/On_trans.svg" />
        </button>
        <button  class="sound-control-item" id="unmute-btn">
            <img src="/assets/Off_trans.svg" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
```

My CSS3 code is

```
.sound-control{
    padding:10px;
    z-index:1000000;

}
.sound-control-item{
    width:40px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size:18px;
    outline:none;
    color:white;
    z-index:9999999;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-radius:100%;
    border-color:transparent;
    border:none; 
}
#mute-btn{
    display: none;
}
```

I also tried the following stackoverflow answers but no luck.

1 - [Safari Cuts off fixed image at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169178/safari-cuts-off-fixed-image-at-the-bottom)

2 - [iOS - Safari - images not rendering fully / cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58323768/ios-safari-images-not-rendering-fully-cut-off)

Comment: Not all modern CSS attributes are compatible across all browsers. You might wanna have a look at 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp.

I suspect it's the z-index in this case.

If you could share a minimalistic replica of your working code on StackBlitz, it'll be helpful for others to assist you.

Comment: Also, it's kinda misleading to say the image is being chopped off. Probably you should edit the title as well in order to get better support from the community.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 
"Safari rendering partial image including ( png, svg ) formats" what do you think about the title

Comment: okay, i will share it on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my issue resolved. The culprit was the button's height & width property.
I was giving the image `width:50px` ( which was child to button) whereas the button ( parent in this case ) was of `width:40px`.

Chrome and Firefox seems to handle this width-problem automatically but safari was unable to handle this.

```
sound-control-item{
    width:50px; # I changed this from 40px -> 50px
    height:auto; # I changed this from 40px -> auto
    font-size:18px;
    outline:none;
    color:white;
    z-index:9999999;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-radius:100%;
    border-color:transparent;
    border:none; 
}
```